# Replace multiple characters with multiple replacers in Perl

Tags: perl

I am updating a piece of code to read a table into R. The delimiters in the table should be semicolons. Some of the elements in the table have semicolons and should be replaced with colons. At the same time, the code is replacing tabs with semicolons and this should be kept.

The current script has the line

```
sprintf("%s -e '%s' | perl -pe 's/\t/;/g' > %s", hive.cmd, sql, tmp_file)
```

and should be updated to, in order:

1. Replace `;` with `:`
2. Replace `\t` with `;`

Edit: I should add I have no experience in Perl.

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: I have no experience in Perl and am a little pressed for time: I hope the solution is simple but don't have the time to teach myself the basics at the moment.

Comment: Posting a question on the internet isn't the best way to get help if you're "a little pressed for time". Can I recommend offering experts money in exchange for their skills?

Answer (score 4):

Perl has the "transliteration" operator (`tr/.../.../`) for doing work like this.

```
$string =~ tr/\t;/;:/;
```

Using the substitution operator for this is overkill.

Answer (score -1):

A simple another way to replace the strings:

```
$str = "\;  \:\;    ";
```

Need to find the two matches `\;` and `\t` we can search the both of them in a single regex and replace to the corresponding value matches.

```
$str=~s/((\;)|\t)/$2 ? '\:' : '\;'/eg;
           ^   ^
```

`$2` matches with `semicolon` and rest of the one matches with `\t` delimits.

```
print $str;
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but this seems like a really complicated way to write `tr/\t;/;:/` :-)

Comment: @DaveCross yes, but this is the approach to take if some of the search or replace strings were multiple characters; well worth having as an alternate answer

Comment: @ysth: Agreed. Which is why (as I said) I haven't downvoted.